# Designer can't read config file

Tags: c#, wpf, designer

I have a WPF application and the designer shows a lot of error messages but the actual program works fine.

The core of the problem seems to be the inability of the designer to find a connection string in the config

> InvalidOperationException: No connection string named
>   'HeliDataDBEntities' could be found in the application config file.

The config contains

```xml
  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="HeliDataDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Database.csdl|res://*/Database.ssdl|res://*/Database.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=...;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

While it's not affecting the actual code, losing the WYSIWYG element of the designer is annoying, and having the error list full of errors that aren't affecting code compilation is making it harder to spot any real errors.

Is there a reason that the designer can't find this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Config files are relative to the application starting. Guess what the application is for the designer - visual studio.

You break best practices. The designer should not connect to the database at all (under pretty much no circumstances) and work with fake data.

Check via

> DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this);

Whether you are in design mode - if you are, do not even try accessing the database.

Comment: Thanks i wasn't aware of the DesignerProperties class, i didn't want the designer to connect to the database, however i didn't know how to build a working model with out database connections that the designer could instantiate for it intellisence functionality, now with the DesignerProperties class i can instruct it to follow different behaviour when the designer is spawning objects to check their structures

Comment: Yes, that is the standard way to do it. Btw., I consider having the db connection in the config file EXTREMELY BAD PRACTICE - I have my configs always in self managed files. Why? The app.config lives in the install directory which is NOT changeable by normal users, and should not be changed by admins. And i never embedd the db config string in installers ;)

Comment: ms by default embeds them in the config, i tend to leave auto generate MS alone until i'm ready to release the product as if if have to make database changes and regenerate the EF model MS will either undo the changes or throw a fit because things aren't where they expect them to be

Comment: I never use this ridiculous default. I also isolate the db classes in their own project - so the ridiculous app.config entry there does not disturb me at all (that app.config just never gets redistributed). VS is happy, I am happy and I have the database isolated from the actual code.